# Confusion with for loop in c# programming language

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in C# programming language and I confused with a question. I have a for loop that increase two times by one in one cycle, but in each cycle it increase once.

What is the reason it does omit the `i++`?

```
string inValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i + 1);
    inValue = Console.ReadLine();                   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `++` increment operator increases value only by one

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

To increase twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2)
{
    Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i);                 
}
```

Read more: [Increment (++) and Decrement (--) Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzcawzfw(v=vs.100).aspx)

> ```
> |      If     |    Equivalent Action   |    Return value           |
> |  variable++ |      variable += 1     |  value of variable before |
> |             |                        |     incrementing          |
> ```

---

The following row:

```
Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i + 1);
```

increases the value of `i` by plus `1` but that is not stored into `i`. It is like writing:

```
int b = i+1; // i is  not affected. New value never stored back into i
Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", b);
```

Any of the following ways will increase value by 2:

```
//Option 1
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i +=2)

//Option2
Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i++);

//Option3
i = i+1;
Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i);
```

Comment: at first it starts addition by one in the console.writeline(i+1); so why it does not increase inside the for (i++) , it increase like this.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` means you just increase the `i` by 1 or simply you can just write the code like this `i = i + 1`. So if you want loop with increase `i + 2`, you can write down code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2)
{
   Console.Write("Enter Score{0}: ", i);
   inValue = Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

The loop will increase `i` by 2.

Answer (score 0):

(i++) increases i by 1, it's like writing : i = i + 1.
(i + 1) does not increases i.

Comment: when i run this code it displays like this  Enter score 1: Enter score 2: Enter score 3: so why it does increase just once?

Comment: actually i did not your first answer completely it was the answer for me sorry for that.